# Issue with scope using jQuery.proxy() and jQuery.on() methods

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to go further with the jQuery.proxy() method using it in a jQuery.on() but I'm stuck at a point because of the scope of the multiple 'this' involved.

This is the classic way to use jQuery.proxy() :

```
var obj = {
  somevar: 'some value',
  doSomething: function() {
    alert(this.somevar);
  }
};
$('div').click( $.proxy(obj.doSomething, obj) ); // -> 'some value'
```

Ok great, but... I would like to get some info from 'div' to send it to 'doSomething'...

```
function Foo(element) {
  this.element = element;
  this.init();
}
Foo.prototype = {
  init: function () {
    this.element.on('click', 'button', $.proxy(function () {
      // trying to send the type of the button to the doSomething method
      this.doSomething( $(this).attr('type') );
    }, this));
  },
  doSomething: function (data) {
    alert(data); // -> 'undefined'
  }
};

var Bar = new Foo( $('div') );
```

Of course it doesn't work because the 'this' inside the '$(this)' is not the jQuery button object...
The only solution I found is to modify a bit the 'init' method :

```
  init: function () {
    var that = this;
    this.element.on('click', 'button', function () {
      that.doSomething( $(this).attr('type') );
    });
  },
```

Is there any way to use the $.proxy() method instead of this 'that' variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you bind a different `this` to the event handler, naturally you can't use `this` to refer to the element that the event occurred on. Your choices instead are to accept the event argument passed to the handler (say, `e`), and then use [`e.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) (the element in which the event originates) or [`e.currentTarget`](http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/) (the element on which you hooked the event, which is normally `this` if you don't use `$.proxy`).

For example, consider:

```
<div id="foo"><span>Click here</span></div>
```

and

```
$("#foo").on("click", $.proxy(function(e) {
    // code here
}, someObject));
```

If you click the `span` above (the text `Click here`), then as of `code here`, `e.target` is the span (where the event actually originated), `e.currentTarget` is the `div` (where you hooked the event), and of course `this` is `someObject`.

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ESEgIp/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ESEgIp/1/edit)

Comment: Following your instructions, I used `this.doSomething( $(event.target).attr('type') );` instead of the line above (in my example) and it worked! Thank you!